# In a linear regression, what happens when you run a regression on $N$ with $p=N$ predictors?

Tags: regression

In a linear regression, suppose we have $N=500$ observations. Then suppose that I ran a regression of dependent $Y$ against independent $X_1, \ldots, X_p$, where $p=500$ as well. What happens in this case and how would it relate to a residual regression formula? I'm also wondering what's the effect on R^2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the R squared of a regression where none of the variables are collinear?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597690/what-is-the-r-squared-of-a-regression-where-none-of-the-variables-are-collinear): if by "independent", you mean they are linearly independent as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{500}$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Yes, how can I also relate it to the residual regression formula?

Comment: The residual will be $0$.  An on-line answer is: the projection (hat) matrix $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T = XX^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}X^T = I_{(500)}$ under your assumption (because $X$ is invertible), whence the residual vector $\hat{\epsilon} = y - Hy = y - y = 0$, which further implies $R^2 = 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong May I ask which part of the above is the residual regression formula?

Comment: "$\hat{\epsilon} = y - Hy$" is the formula to calculate residual (this is in matrix form).  You may want to read [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation) if this sounds unfamiliar.